# Getting the uploading file name before upload with jQuery File Upload plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the jQuery File Upload plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki to upload multiple files to the server. I'll be using it with a custom web service which will store the uploaded images on the server. However, besides of the POST request body I'll also need to pass to the web service the name of the file which is being uploaded. So, with each file transfer I'll also need to pass to the web service the name of the file. Could anybody tell me how can I take the file name and send it with each upload request? I'll basically need to get it from the  field, without any additional input field. If a user chose 10 files, I'll need to take the name for each file in the queue and submit it with the upload request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution which works:

```
// Storing the file name in the queue
var fileName = "";

// On file add assigning the name of that file to the variable to pass to the web service
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
  $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
    fileName = file.name;
  });
});

// On file upload submit - assigning the file name value to the form data
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
  data.formData = {"file" : fileName};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of what kind of web service your site used, resume that is ashx, if that
you can use

```
HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
```

to fetch the filename;

or use jquery

```
$("#yourid").uploadify({
.....
    'onSelect': function(e, queueId, fileObj)
    {
        alert( "FileName：" + fileObj.name);
    }
});
```

// jquery-file-upload

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
drop: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        alert('Dropped file: ' + file.name);
    });
},
change: function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        alert('Selected file: ' + file.name);
    });
}
```

});

Comment: I need to get the file name on client side and submit with the POST request of the file upload.

Comment: I do not use uploadify - it's Flash dependant. I'm using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#callbacks there is the answer like uploadify

Comment: you have solved my issue by `onSelect` function... because I want to do something before upload start...and no other functions helped me even `onStartUpload` or `onUplad`... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
```