# Jquery-File-Upload How do I get the name of a picture uploaded saved as a form variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Jquery-File-Upload to upload a picture as part of an online trip application.  I'm not that familiar with javascript.  How can I save the picture name as a variable field of my http application form, which I will subsequently post to a php page.  While jquery-file-upload allows muliple files, I only need it to upload one file.  If someone does upload multiple pictures, I only need the name of the last one to survive as a form variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the current jquery-File-Upload script in the html file

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
   'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
    }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

I don't know where I would add any additional code.

Comment: Can you show us some code? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266040/getting-the-uploading-file-name-before-upload-with-jquery-file-upload-plugin

Comment: this is the current jquery-File-Upload script in the html file

Comment: Calvin, it looks like the solution there might do it, but I don't know how to add that code into my existing page.

Comment: what do you mean by saying `form variable.` ?

Comment: I have an html form called regform.  In my javascripts if I want to work with one of the field variables  I use a format  like document.regform.first_name.value == "".  I want the name of the uploaded picture to be assigned to a variable in regform that I can post to a php document.