# jQuery File Upload multiple filenames

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I'm using cycero's excellent [additions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266040/getting-the-uploading-file-name-before-upload-with-jquery-file-upload-plugin) to Sebastian Tschan's jQuery File upload to submit the filename at the same time.

```
// Storing the file name in the queue
var fileName = "";

// On file add assigning the name of that file to the variable to pass to the web service
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            fileName = file.name;
        });
    });

// On file upload submit - assigning the file name value to the form data
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        data.formData = {"imagefilename" : fileName};
    });
```

Unfortunately when I do a multi-file upload it posts the same filename for all files rather than a filename each.

How do I create a filename field/argument for each file?

https://dev.over60travel.com/sandbox/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

Comment: How you declared 'fileName' variable is a common instance. So it will keep overwriting with the latest value when you first loop through. Try using an array and pushing the filenames and retrieve on submit.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that code was for a simpler form.

Unless I'm mistaken, the form is built with javascript and then when you opt to Upload All it loops through the form and repeatedly invokes the upload handler. I can't really work out where the form is built and how to add a filename array element to it though.